# Removing stuff from ArrayList with iterator while its still being used

Tags: java, android, arraylist, iterator

I have made a little game which draws enemies on the screen, the enemies are from an ArrayList. The screen gets redrawn so that the enemies can also move. I do this with this code:

```
for (Meteor m : getMeteorArrayList()) {
    if (m.getVisible())
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(m.getImg(), m.getX(), m.getY(), p);
    }
    else
    {
        Iterator<Meteor> iter = getMeteorArrayList().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext())
        {
            if (iter.next() == m)
            {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

But this gives a problem. If I kill an enemy, I want it to be removed from the ArrayList. I know I can set it to NULL but then it still exists. I use an `Iterator` for this as you can see in the code above.

The problem with this is that if the screen is redrawn after I removed an enemy the application crashes with this error:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
```

I think it is because I suddenly have a hole in my ArrayList on the place where the enemy was.
How can I make it so that I can remove something from the ArrayList and still access the rest ?

Comment: @onepotato Please rethink your review-style. Accepting an edit where you need to revert most of the edit isn't appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the point. I only improved the previous edit because it still contains wrong grammar.

Comment: @onepotato You accepted the reviewed edit and you had to revert most of the edit to correct it. You still can accept such edits, but it is better to reject them and edit only the missing parts, without the need to revert the wrong stuff of the reviewed edit. That's what I meant.

Comment: @Tom Looking at the edit history, it seems that its not me who reverted most of your edit. Its the guy who edit that question after you and before me. Please check.

Comment: @onepotato I'm not talking about my reverted edits :P. I'm talking about the stuff you've fixed during the edit review. You had to fix quite a lot of stuff of the edit you've reviewed to since this edit made some stuff worse. What I want to say is, that it is mostly better/easier to reject the reviewed edit to avoid manually fixing the wrong stuff of the edit and add the few correct parts yourself. But this is just my "review style" you still can do it differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you are iterating over the list twice - once implicitly (with the enhanced for loop) and a second time with an explicit iterator. If you only use an explicit iterator, you'll be able to remove the element from the list.

```
    Iterator<Meteor> iter = getMeteorArrayList().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext ()) {
        Meteor m = iter.next ();
        if (m.getVisible()) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(m.getImg(), m.getX(), m.getY(), p);
        } else {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use only the iterator

```
Iterator<Meteor> iter = getMeteorArrayList().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Metor m = iter.next();
    if (m.getVisible()) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

the exception is probably caused because you are iterating twice over the same list